# C diceroll game

Tags: c, windows, dice

I wanted to create a dice game but it's always saying my guess is wrong and idk why.
I finally understand how to make the rand function actually random btw :D
I think it's because the array isn't storing the strings correctly.

```
int main()
{

srand(time(NULL));
int dice1 = 1, dice2 = 1, dice3 = 1, sum, key = 0;
int dice4 = 1, dice5 = 1, dice6 = 1, sum2;
char randomnumber[10];

printf("Diceroll-game \n\n");
printf("The first sum is:\n");


dice1 = (rand()%6 + 1);
dice2 = (rand()%6 + 1);
dice3 = (rand()%6 + 1);

sum = dice1 + dice2 + dice3;

printf("%d\n", sum);

printf("Will the next sum of 3 dices be higher(hi), lower (lo) or the same(sa) (hi, lo, sa)?\n");
printf("Type hi, lo or sa\n");

scanf("%c \n", &randomnumber);

dice4 = (rand()%6 + 1);
dice5 = (rand()%6 + 1);
dice6 = (rand()%6 + 1);

sum2 = dice4 + dice5 + dice6;

if (randomnumber == "hi" && sum2 > sum) {
   printf("You were right !\n\a");

}else {
    if (key == 0) {
printf("You were wrong.");
key = 1;
}
}


if (randomnumber == "lo" && sum2 < sum) {
   printf("You were right !\n\a");

}else {
    if (key == 0) {
printf("You were wrong.");
key = 1;
}
}


if (randomnumber == "sa" && sum2 == sum) {
   printf("You were right !\n\a");

}else {
    if (key == 0) {
printf("You were wrong.");
key = 1;
}
}



printf("\nIt's %d", sum2);

return 0;
```

Can someone help me please.
Thank you.

Comment: I still have the key variable and it's now saying "You were wrong.You were right!"

Comment: Bucky creates horrible tutorials and exercises. Get yourself a book, mate! P.S. `rand` is a *pseudo-random number generator*, not a *true random number generator*.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour , Who is 'bucky'?

Comment: @CoolGuy Bucky seems to be the origin of [this challenge](https://www.thenewboston.com/forum/topic.php?id=1217), betwixt a tonne of [poor tutorials and undefined behaviour (e.g. buffer overflows)](https://www.thenewboston.com/forum/topic.php?id=1157)... Don't bother trying to point out any issues with him; there's no way anything he ever creates could have problems ;)

Answer (score 2):

- **Firstly,** You're using wrong format specifier here. `%c` is used to scan one `char`. You need to use `%s` for a *string*. Using wrong format specifier  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

  Then, the *format string* you supply to `scanf()` needs to match the input exactly. You don't need a `newline` there.

  Also, `randomnumber` being an array, adding `&` while using that as `scanf()` argument is not required.

  Change

  ```
  scanf("%c \n", &randomnumber);
  ```

  to

  ```
  scanf("%s", randomnumber);
  ```
- **Secondly**, string comaprisons cannot be done using `==` operator. You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to compare two string contents.

  Change

  ```
  .. randomnumber == "hi" ...
  ```

  to

  ```
  ..  !strcmp(randomnumber, "hi")   ...
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Three problems:

1. You are using the wrong format specifier for scanning a string. `%c` is used for a `char` while `%s` is used for strings. So change

   ```
   scanf("%c \n", &randomnumber);
   ```

   to

   ```
   scanf("%s", randomnumber);
   ```

   Other changes I made is removing the `\n` and space character as it will not stop scanning until a non-whitespace character, which is probably not what you want. Also, `%s` expects a `char*`. `&randomnumber` is of type `char(*)[10]` while `randomnumber` gets converted to `&randomnumber[0]`, a `char*`, which is exactly what `%s` wants to have.
2. In C, when you compare strings using `==`, you compare pointers and not the actual content. To compare the contents, include `string.h` and use `strcmp`. It returns 0 if both the strings are equal. So change the following:

   ```
   if (randomnumber == "hi" && sum2 > sum) {
   if (randomnumber == "lo" && sum2 < sum) {
   if (randomnumber == "sa" && sum2 == sum) {
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (strcmp(randomnumber, "hi") == 0 && sum2 > sum) {
   if (strcmp(randomnumber, "lo") == 0 && sum2 < sum) {
   if (strcmp(randomnumber, "sa") == 0 && sum2 == sum) {
   ```
3. Now, after you've fixed the other problems, you'll notice that some things print twice, which is not probably what you want. The reason is that you have three `if`s with `strcmp`s. Only one can be true at most which will print `"You were right !\n"` and the rest will print `"You were wrong."`. Fix it by changing

   ```
   if (strcmp(randomnumber, "hi") == 0 && sum2 > sum) {
      printf("You were right !\n\a");

   }else {
       if (key == 0) {
   printf("You were wrong.");
   key = 1;
   }
   }


   if (strcmp(randomnumber, "lo") == 0 && sum2 < sum) {
      printf("You were right !\n\a");

   }else {
       if (key == 0) {
   printf("You were wrong.");
   key = 1;
   }
   }


   if (strcmp(randomnumber, "sa") == 0 && sum2 == sum) {
      printf("You were right !\n\a");

   }else {
       if (key == 0) {
   printf("You were wrong.");
   key = 1;
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (strcmp(randomnumber, "hi") == 0 && sum2 > sum) {
      printf("You were right !\n\a");
   }else if(strcmp(randomnumber, "lo") == 0 && sum2 < sum) {
      printf("You were right !\n\a");
   }else if(strcmp(randomnumber, "sa") == 0 && sum2 == sum) {
      printf("You were right !\n\a");
   }else {
       if (key == 0) {
          printf("You were wrong.");
       key = 1;
   }
   ```

Note that the `key` variable is superfluous in your program.

Comment: Very right about the second point. I stopped at the first point itself. Good catch, +1.

Comment: @DavisR5 , Check problem number 3 in the edited answer.